# C# http post response returning valid cookie but browser displays script error / session expired

Tags: c#, forms, http, post, submit

Coding a bot to sign me in for a list of courses at my uni for which at the end i get redirected to a payment service site.

I was able to login, add courses and check necessary checkboxes via HTTP POST although am completely stuck at the last input-form that is supposed to redirect me to the paymet service. (at the moment i coded a workaround using WebBrowser and HtmlElement.InvokeMember("click") just so it works for the time)

Tried using firefox network analysis to inspect POST parameters although there it only shows "_ul: 1".
If i compare the cookie from firefox (clicking manually) with the cookie i get from my c# code through response.Headers["Set-cookie"] they seems to match in their pattern. So i believe the cookie i get actually is valid.

html section ("asdf1234" is a placeholder for the hidden value):

```html
<form target="_top" method="post" action="https://payments.kalixa.com/Checkout/PaymentMethods/" name="formular">
    <div class="alert alert-warning">
        <p style="text-align:center">
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Next"/>
        </p>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" value="asdf1234" name="requestData"/>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        //document.formular.submit();
    </script>
</form>
```

c# section:

```cs
string formUrl = redirectUrl;
string formParams = string.Format("requestData={0}", "asdf1234");
request = WebRequest.Create(formUrl);
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.Method = "POST";
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams);
request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
using (Stream os = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
response = request.GetResponse();
cookieHeader = response.Headers["Set-cookie"];


using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), enc))
{
    pageSource = sr.ReadToEnd();
}

response.Close();
```

The error i get is at first a message box captioned "script error" row "5" character "2"  error "The value of the property "$" is null or undefined, no function-object" (transalted from german) code "0"

After clicking yes or no the pageSource variable contains the html of a session-expired landing page.

Comment: "$" is null or undefined

is normally jQuery is undefined, have you got a reference to that in your file?

Comment: I agree with @Rav, my guess would be that you relying on jQuery and it is not present. Does the page you are contacting via your C# code have jQuery? If not, you might have to consider using vanilla javascript

Comment: @Rav the page containing the form has no reference to jQuery.

Comment: @JamieTaylor the page where the payment is done (the one i cant get to without clicking the button) is loaded with js and jQuery

Comment: $ is normally associated with jQuery, maybe you're using a plugin that has a dependency on jQuery.

Comment: If you're using bootstrap and from your classes I assume you are, Bootstrap's javascript functions rely on jquery

Comment: basically i just want to simulate the button click without using the WebBrowser control and only http post and cookies instead while my problem is that i tried all i know and am out of ideas on where to look for the problem or even what to search for in google

Comment: @Rav sorry i dont even know what that means (im just using a basic windows forms application in visual studio if that helps in any way). but if thats the case what do i need to look up / read into in order to potentially be able to solve the issue? thanks for trying to help btw. appreciate it alot!

Comment: Try this, when you're on the form, open up google develeoper f12 and then type in the following 

$('form').html()

if you get another $ is undefined, it's a jQuery not being loaded or if no error then your javascript is being being loaded prior to the DOM. You can try and wrap up the javascript in a 

$(function(){ //insert javascript here... });

Comment: The thing is i dont know what kind of javascript code is executed. //document.formular.submit(); is the actual thing writtein the original html. its not a placeholder like the "asdf1234" in my posted code. nevertheless, since i dont understand a bit about jquery and javascript i probalby have to dig into that before any of your answers make sense to me. i appreciate your effort though. thanks!